# pass aspx variable from one page to another

Tags: asp.net, t-sql

i am doing a project which implements users and groups. i display the groups in a gridview on one page. this gridview has a buttonfield, when i click this buttonfield another page opens with a list of users. the reason is that i want to choose which users will be added to this group. the only thing missing is how do i get the groupid(gruppenid) from one page (where the list of groups is displayed) onto the other (where the list of users is displayed)?

here is my code:

Group page markup

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlGruppe" ScrollBars="Both" runat="server">
    <asp:Button ID="btnNeueGruppe" Text="Neue Gruppe" runat="server" OnClick="btnNeueGruppe_Click" />
    <asp:GridView DataKeyNames="GruppenID" OnRowCommand="grdGruppe_RowCommand" ID="grdGruppe" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Bezeichnung" HeaderText="Bezeichnung" SortExpression="Bezeichnung" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Mitglieder anzeigen">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnMitgliederAnzeigen" runat="server" Text="Mitglieder anzeigen" CommandName="MitgliederAnzeigen"
                        CommandArgument='<%# Eval("GruppenID") %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:CommandField HeaderText="Archivieren" ButtonType="Button" ShowDeleteButton="true" DeleteText="Archivieren" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Mitglieder anzeigen">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnMitgliederHinzufuegen" runat="server" Text="Mitglieder hinzufügen" CommandName="MitgliederHinzufuegen"
                        CommandArgument='<%# Eval("GruppenID") %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>"
        SelectCommand="SELECT [Bezeichnung], [GruppenID] FROM [Gruppe] WHERE [Archiviert] != 1"
        DeleteCommand="UPDATE Gruppe SET [Archiviert] = 1 WHERE [GruppenID] = @GruppenID; DELETE FROM BenutzerGruppe WHERE [GruppenID] = @GruppenID">            
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:Button ID="btnZurueck" Text="Zurück" runat="server" OnClick="btnZurueck_Click" />
</asp:Panel>
```

Relevant code-behind of group page

```
protected void grdGruppe_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
             if (e.CommandName == "MitgliederHinzufuegen")
        {
            Response.Redirect("MitgliederHinzufuegen.aspx?GruppenID=" + e.CommandArgument);
        }
        }
```

Markup of age where users will be added to group

```
 <asp:Content ID="content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">           
        <asp:GridView OnRowCommand="grdBenutzer_RowCommand" DataKeyNames="BenutzerID" ID="grdBenutzer" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField ReadOnly="true" DataField="BenutzerID" HeaderText="ID" />                   
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Bezeichnung">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <%# Eval("Bezeichnung")%>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList AppendDataBoundItems="true" runat="server" ID="ddwnBezeichnung" Text='<%# Bind("Bezeichnung")%>'>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Mitarbeiter" Value="Mitarbeiter"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Praktikant" Value="Praktikant"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Azubi" Value="Azubi"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Umschüler" Value="Umschüler"></asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Vorname">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <%# Eval("Vorname")%>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtVorname" Text='<%# Bind("Vorname")%>' />
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Nachname">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <%# Eval("Nachname")%>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtNachname" Text='<%# Bind("Nachname")%>' />
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField ReadOnly="true" HeaderText="Geburtsdatum" DataField="Geburtsdatum" />                    
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Benutzerart">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <%# Eval("Benutzerart")%>
                    </ItemTemplate>                        
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" HeaderText="Mitglied hinzufügen" Text="Mitglied hinzufügen" CommandName="MitgliedHinzufuegen" />
            </Columns>              
        </asp:GridView>
     <asp:SqlDataSource OnInserted="SqlDataSource1_Inserted" ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>"
        SelectCommand="SELECT [BenutzerID], [Bezeichnung], [Vorname], [Geburtsdatum], [Nachname], [Benutzerart] FROM [Benutzer] WHERE [Archiviert] != 1">            
     </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Relevant code-behind of page where users are added

```
 protected void grdBenutzer_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "MitgliedHinzufuegen")
        {
            string gruppenid = Request.QueryString["GruppenID"];
            SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters.Add("GruppenID", gruppenid);
            SqlDataSource1.InsertCommand="INSERT INTO BenutzerGruppe (BenutzerID, GruppenID) VALUES (@BenutzerID, @GruppenID)";
            SqlDataSource1.Insert();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the variable using `QueryString`.

```
protected void grdGruppe_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "MitgliederHinzufuegen")
    {
        Response.Redirect("MitgliederHinzufuegen.aspx?gruppenid=" + Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument));
    }
}
```

And retrieve it on the other page using:

```
Request.QueryString["gruppenid"]
```

Comment: ok i got it working up to the part that i can access the groupid from the code-behind part of the page for adding users. i create the insert-command in the SqlDataSource_Inserting part. but it doesnt seem to be called when i debug...any idea why? i have updated the code above...

Comment: u mean to say ur debugger doesnt reach on Inserting event?

Comment: nope...that is whats baffling me, normally this should work but nothing in the event is being called

Comment: elaborate what do you wanna achieve? i would suggest you to use the InsertCommand property just like you used the SelectCommand property

Comment: how do i do that? i don't know how to pass the code-behind variable to the aspx part of the page...

Comment: you should write the inserting thing that you wrote above inside the rowcommand event instead of Inserting event. You can use the Insert method inside the rowcommand event.

Comment: ok i have updated my code...it seems the insert is being done now but no new data is inserted...

Answer (score 1):

You can pass gruppenid using [QueryString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.querystring.aspx)

```
protected void grdGruppe_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.CommandName == "MitgliederHinzufuegen")
     {
        Response.Redirect("MitgliederHinzufuegen.aspx?gruppenid" + GroupID);
     }
}
```

Comment: ok but i cant access the groupid variable as it is declared in the .aspx part of the page. how do i make it accessible in code-behind so i can pass it with the redirect method?

Comment: pls see comments in other answer, i got the request thing working...now i only need to modify the insert-statement to use the groupid